# Java Doubly Linked List removeLast()

Tags: java

I have a class assignment that required me to create a class DoubleList that implements a ListADT.

I've gotten to the point where the code ALMOST works correctly. The output for the code should be:
1 3 7 9 13 14 16 17 23 24
3 9 13 16

My output is:
1 3 7 9 13 14 16 17 23 24
3 9 13 16 **23**

The first removeLast() seems to remove the 24 but for some reason the 23 stays after the second removeLast() is called. Please help!

EDIT: If I call removeLast() another time, it removes the 23.

```
class DoubleList<T> implements ListADT<T>{

    private int _size;
    private DoubleNode _head;
    private DoubleNode _tail;

    public DoubleList() {
        _size = 0;
        _head = null;
        _tail = null;
    }

    public T removeFirst(){
        if(_size == 0){
            return null;
        }
        DoubleNode tmp = _head;
        _head = _head._next;
        _head._previous = null;
        _size--;
        return tmp._value;
    }

    public T removeLast(){
        if(_size == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        T temp = _tail._value;
        _tail = _tail._previous;
        _tail._next = null;
        _size--;
        return temp;
    }

    public T remove(T element){
        if(_size == 0){
            return null;
        }

        DoubleNode current = _head;
        DoubleNode previous = null;
        T temp = null;

        do{
            if(current._value == element){
                temp = current._value;
                if(previous == null){
                    _head = _head._next;
                    _head._previous = null;
                }
                else{
                    previous._next = current._next;
                }
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current._next;
        }while(current != null);
        return temp;
    }

    public T first(){
        return _head._value;
    }

    public T last(){
        return _tail._value;
    }

    public boolean contains(T target){
        if(_size == 0){
            return false;
        }

        DoubleNode temp = _head;

        do{
            if(temp._value == target){
                return true;
            }
            temp = temp._next;
        }while(temp != null);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        if(_size == 0){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int size(){
        return _size;
    }

    public void add(T element)
    {
        int add = 0;
        DoubleNode temp = new DoubleNode();
        temp._value = element;
        DoubleNode point = _head;
        DoubleNode placeHolder;

        if(_head == null) {
            _head = temp;
            _tail = temp;
            _size++;
            return;
        }
        else if((Integer)element <= (Integer)_head._value){
            temp._next = _head;
            _head._previous = temp;
            _head = temp;
            _size++;
            return;
        }

        do {

            if(point._next == null){
                point._next = temp;
                temp._previous = point;
                _tail = temp;
                _size++;
                return;
            }
            else if((Integer)point._next._value >= (Integer)element && (Integer)point._value < (Integer)element){
                placeHolder = point._next;
                point._next = temp;
                placeHolder._previous = temp;
                temp._next = placeHolder;
                temp._previous = point;
                _size++;
                return;
            }

            point = point._next;

        } while (point != null);


        _size++;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String returnString = "";
        if(_size == 0){
            return returnString;
        }

        DoubleNode temp = _head;

        do{
            returnString += temp._value + " ";
            temp = temp._next;
        }while(temp != null);
        return returnString;
    }



    private class DoubleNode {
        private DoubleNode _previous;
        private DoubleNode _next;
        private T _value;

        public DoubleNode() {
            _previous = null;
            _next = null;
            _value = null;
        }

        public DoubleNode(T value){
            _previous = null;
            _next = null;
            _value = value;
        }

    }

}

/**
 * DoubleOrderedList testing area.
 *
 * @author (your name), Acuna
 * @version (version)
 */
class Driver {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        DoubleList<Integer> list = new DoubleList<>();

        //RA: These are _extremely_ simple tests - do not use them when doing
        //    your writeup.

        list.add(23);
        list.add(24);
        list.add(16);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(17);
        list.add(9);
        list.add(13);
        list.add(14);
        list.add(1);
        System.out.println("\nsize = " + list.size());

        System.out.println(list);

        list.remove(7);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.removeFirst();
        System.out.println(list);
        list.remove(17);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.removeLast();
        System.out.println(list);
        list.remove(14);
        System.out.println(list);
        list.removeLast();
        System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Please explain what is the intent of your program i.e. how the given input will return the expected output. Also Which ListADT class are you referring to here

Comment: Your example is quite long for your specific issue. It's perfectly on topic here (I think) but I'm sure you would get more feedback on your whole code from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: The program is a doubly linked list that will store elements. We are working with integers for ease of use. The ADT is something we had to implement ourselves as part of the assignment. The logic for removing the last item doesn't seem to function correctly.
EDIT: I can post just the portion I'm having issues with but I think it would be more confusing if you couldn't see the entire logic.

Comment: A simple way to debug this would be to write a method that starts at the head of the list and traverses the list printing each element. You could call the method after each list modification is made to ensure what you want to happen is happening

Comment: I've actually done this. The removeLast has to be called once for the 24 to be removed but twice for the 23 to be removed from the end and I'm not sure what's causing this behavior.

Comment: Didnt see that. I'll see if I can run it on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your bug is in `removeLast`. It's in the `remove` function, and it corrupts your list, causing further manipulations of the list to behave incorrectly.

When you remove an item from the middle of a double linked list, you need to stitch up the item before the removed item, **and** the item after the removed item. You are doing the first operation, but not the second. For example, suppose I have three elements in the list: L X R. I want to remove X. I have to set L._next = R (you do that), and also set R._previous = L (you don't do that). At that point, your list becomes corrupt, because your reverse links are off.

Comment: Perfect. The first paragraph was plenty enough information for me to find the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your loop at remove function.

```
do{
            if(current._value == element){
                temp = current._value;
                if(previous == null){
                    _head = _head._next;
                    _head._previous = null;
                }
                else{
                    previous._next = current._next;
                    //next line is missing
                    previous._next._previous = previous;
                }
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current._next;
        }while(current != null);
```

Also, it's not efficient to loop while(current != null), consider (while !found && current != null) or break statement.